# What is a prime sequence? Is it a sequence that repeats a prime number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

What is a Prime sequence? Like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSXM9nT7hRE)?

Comment: It is a sequence whose terms belong to the set of prime numbers. But when you refer to THE sequence of prime numbers, then it means that it is the sequence $2,3,5,7,11,13,17, \dots$ where all primes appear exactly once in increasing order.

Comment: this video is some sort of non-sense

Comment: I would say that "a prime sequence" is simply a sequence that consists only of prime numbers, whether it's distinct prime numbers or repeated prime numbers.

Comment: But after watching the video, I believe that the person who uploaded it has completely misunderstood the Riemann hypothesis and the Millennium Prize Problems. http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/millennium-prize-problems Furthermore, I strongly doubt he has the "100,000$" on hand.